# Probability in number guessing game?

Tags: probability

An oracle picks a number $W$ randomly on the uniform distribution $U(0,10)$. This is the "winning" index. $N$ other players each pick a single number over the same distribution.

I pick a specific number $S$ from the same distribution (but I *pick* some number consciously, mine is not random - thanks to *joriki* pointing out ambiguity ).

The winner is the player with the least number picked that is $>=W$ (if any).

What is the probability that my specific number $S$ wins?

My first thought was this would just be the probability $a<=S<=b$ where $a,b$ are the first and second order statistic of the distribution, representing the oracle and the least "other player" greater than $W$, but I'm convinced that's completely wrong.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change in the question has broken the nice symmetry of the question in which $S$ was picked from the same distribution.

Now you win if there is at least one number less than yours and the greatest number less than yours is $W$. The probability that there is at least one number less than yours is $1-(1-S/10)^{N+1}$, and if there is, then the probability that the number right below yours is $W$ is $1/(N+1)$. Thus now your winning probability is

$$
\frac1{N+1}\left(1-\left(1-\frac S{10}\right)^{N+1}\right)\;.
$$

We can check that this integrates to $1/(N+2)$ if we go back to picking $S$ from $U(0,10)$:

$$
\int_0^{10}\frac{\mathrm dS}{10}\frac1{N+1}\left(1-\left(1-\frac S{10}\right)^{N+1}\right)=\frac1{N+1}\left(1-\frac1{N+2}\right)=\frac1{N+2}\;.
$$

---

*This is the answer to the original question, in which $S$ was picked from the same distribution as the other numbers.*

The game is symmetric among the players, so your winning probability is $1/(N+1)$ times the probability that someone wins. Someone wins unless $W$ is the greatest of $N+2$ numbers, with probability $1/(N+2)$. Thus your winning probability is

$$
\frac1{N+1}\left(1-\frac1{N+2}\right)=\frac1{N+2}\;.
$$

The same result can be obtained with even less arithmetic by closing the interval cyclically and adding an $(N+3)$-rd number that determines where the circle is cut to form the interval. All rankings of the $N+3$ numbers are equiprobable. Whatever the rank of $W$, there is now exactly one of the remaining $N+2$ ranks such that you win if you get it.

Comment: Even our typesetting is the same - we must be right ;-)

Comment: I don't follow - e.g., if I pick zero, the probability of me winning is zero, correct? Does it not depend on the *S* I pick? +1 in any case.

Comment: @rasher: Of course it depends on the $S$ you pick. You said that you pick it from the same distribution. If you want it to be a parameter in the result, you can't specify that it's random. Perhaps you just meant that you pick it from the same *interval*?

Comment: @joriki: Ah, I need to clarify the OP, my apologies, I meant by "specific" that it's not a random choice, I am consciously picking a value, the other players are random... updating.

Comment: Accept - thanks, joriki, I'd had this (or similar), dismissed it when I checked it for being a valid probability distribution - I'd integrated incorrectly. Appreciated.

Comment: @rasher: I'm not sure what you mean by that. It's a probability, not a probability distribution. What were you expecting it to integrate to?

Comment: @joriki: Sorry, I meant *that* was my problem, integrating it as if it *were* a PD, so the result looked wrong, when it was not (IIRC, since I'd tossed that idea already). Long day and was not thinking, thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** This is an answer to the original version of the question.

---

Let's rephrase the question so that the oracle is considered to be one of the $N+2$ players.  Then the probability you are after is
$$P(\hbox{you win})=P(\hbox{you win}\mid\hbox{oracle doesn't win})\,P(\hbox{oracle doesn't win})$$
which by symmetry is
$$\frac{1}{N+1}\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{N+2}\Bigr)=\frac1{N+2}\ .$$

Comment: Just to let you know that the question has changed (breaking the symmetry both of the game and of our typesetting :-).